# using R, how can I go through multiples tabs on an Excel file to extract some data and sent to dataframe?

Tags: r, excel, loops, extract

I have an Excel file which has multiple tabs, I would like to have a function where I can go tab by tab and extract the same column (it is always in the same position of every tab) and sent them to a dataframe, any idea about how to reach this?

#Excel #R

This is an example of the template that I have: [excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ePGfsGXmKaZtIOIP2LdmqV4l9tQ7hqoR/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100545136517288518095&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Is it always 24 values starting in row  of column 5?

Comment: Have you tried using `read.xlsx` from `openxls` library and creating a loop through the `sheet` argument (loop depending on sheet/tab you target)

Comment: Yes, it is always like that. From 0 to 23 I would like to extract the covers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way with packages `readxl` and `cellranger`.
Get the sheet names in `sheets` then loop through them reading column 5, from row 7 to 31.
Change the `path` value (`"~/Temp"`) to the path where your files are.

```
library(readxl)

path <- "~/Temp"
fl <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)

sheets <- excel_sheets(fl)
cells <- cellranger::cell_limits(ul = c(7, 5), lr = c(31, 5))

df1 <- lapply(sheets, \(s) read_excel(path = fl, sheet = s, range = cells))
df1 <- do.call(cbind, df1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
library(openxlsx)
filenamerv<-file.choose() # File name
sheetsrv <- getSheetNames(filenamerv) #get all sheets
SheetListrv <- lapply(sheetsrv,read.xlsx,xlsxFile=filenamerv) #get all data in sheets and store in a list
names(SheetListrv) <- sheetsrv 
names(SheetListrv)
```